# google analytic result to my website

Tags: google-analytics

Anybody know,how i add my google analytic result to my website.like a widget or something.I want to know my site google analytic result from my website itself.Any tools available for this

Thanks,
Companion

Comment: Are you using a CMS or anything similar (like Wordpress, Drupal etc)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use google's [Data Export API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html) to retrieve data from your GA account. But as mentioned by Ewan, if you are using a 3rd party CMS for your site...many of them have this API built into them already, or offer plugins for it.